# Jest test fails when using absolute path, fails to load svg image

Tags: typescript, svg, jestjs, babeljs, vite

I am crating a Typescript React app with vite.
I'm using Jest and babel to run tests for my react app.
I have set up absolute paths to sue throughout the application.

When I try to run my test using relative path for the image it passes. However, when using absolute paths for svg file it fails.

My jest config:

```
module.exports = {
  testEnvironment: 'jest-environment-jsdom',
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^@/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/$1',
    '^@api(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/api$1',
    '^@assets(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/assets$1',
    '^@components(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/components$1',
    '^@hooks(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/hooks$1',
    '^@interfaces(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/interfaces$1',
    '^@layouts(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/layouts$1',
    '^@pages(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/pages$1',
    '^@routes(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/routes$1',
    '^@store(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/store$1',
    '^@utils(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/utils$1',
    // For svg images transformer
    '^.+\\.svg$': 'jest-svg-transformer',
  },
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['./jest.setup.ts'],
};
```

My Vite config:

```
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': path.resolve(__dirname, './src'),
      '@api': path.resolve(__dirname, './src/api'),
      '@assets': path.resolve(__dirname, './src/assets'),
      '@components': path.resolve(__dirname, './src/components'),
      '@hooks': path.resolve(__dirname, './src/hooks'),
      '@interfaces': path.resolve(__dirname, './src/interfaces'),
      '@layouts': path.resolve(__dirname, './src/layouts'),
      '@pages': path.resolve(__dirname, './src/pages'),
      '@routes': path.resolve(__dirname, './src/routes'),
      '@store': path.resolve(__dirname, './src/store'),
      '@utils': path.resolve(__dirname, './src/utils'),
    },
  },
  ...
```

My TS config:

```
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
      "@api/*": ["api/*"],
      "@assets/*": ["assets/*"],
      "@components/*": ["components/*"],
      "@hooks/*": ["hooks/*"],
      "@interfaces/*": ["interfaces/*"],
      "@layouts/*": ["layouts/*"],
      "@pages/*": ["pages/*"],
      "@routes/*": ["routes/*"],
      "@store/*": ["store/*"],
      "@utils/*": ["utils/*"]
    }
```

And finally the component where I'm using it:

```
import loginIcon from '../../assets/images/privacy.svg';  //passes
import loginIcon from '@assets/images/privacy.svg'; //fails

...
  <Box height={64} width={64} mb={4}>
    <img src={loginIcon} width='64' height='64' />
  </Box>
```

I have no idea why this is happening, I guess it could be a jest-svg-transformer feature. But not sure why it fails using absolute paths

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is your `moduleNameMapper` value for `@assets` resolves to `<rootDir>/src/assets$1` instead of `jest-svg-transformer` in your `jest.config.js`.

Try adding an alias for `'^@assets/images(.*)$': 'jest-svg-transformer'`